# How to use views data export?

Tags: views

I would like to use views data export module.
I cannot find a way on this.
Could you please help me on this?
Thanks

Comment: Your question seems somewhat too broad. What version drupal are you using? Have you installed the module? What exactly is it that you'd like to do? Have you had a look through the issue queue over at drupal.org: http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export ?

Comment: HI i installed i dint find where exactly data export option exists

Comment: Check out the module documentation page at http://drupal.org/node/1820452. The screenshots are self explanatory.